# Add an entity in another bundle repository

Tags: symfony

I have a bundle named ActiviteBundle that I use has a service. I can ask that service to return me a specific activite by id from another bundle (named GestigrisBundle that act has a kinda main app). Not a problem so far. My GestigrisBundle has a entity that extends an Abstract Entity situated in the Activite Bundle:

**abstract class:**

```
namespace leseulsteve\ActiviteBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 */
abstract class AbstractActivite
{...
```

**concrete class:**

```
namespace leseulsteve\GestigrisBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use leseulsteve\ActiviteBundle\Entity\AbstractActivite;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="leseulsteve\ActiviteBundle\Entity\ActiviteRepository")
 */
class Demystification extends AbstractActivite
{
```

Now my problem is that I want to get a 'Demystification' from the service situated in the ActiviteBundle. With this code:

**Controller:**

```
namespace leseulsteve\GestiGrisBundle\Controller;

use leseulsteve\GestiGrisBundle\Entity\Demystification;

class DemystificationController extends Controller
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        $service = this->container->get('leseulsteve_activite.activites');
        $demys = $service->getActivite('Demystification', 1);
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
namespace leseulsteve\ActiviteBundle;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class Activites
{
    public function getActivite($entite, $id)
    {
        $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('leseulsteveActiviteBundle:'.$entite);
        $activite = $repository->find($id);
    }
}
```

I get this error message:

> Warning: class_parents(): Class
>   leseulsteve\ActiviteBundle\Entity\Demystification does not exist and
>   could not be loaded in
>   C:\GestiGris3\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService.php
>   line 40

Which I guess has to do with namespaces or something that I'm not that
familiar with yet in php!! Would be lovely if someone could help me with
that! Hope that I have been clear enough too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this :

```
$this->entityManager->getRepository('leseulsteveActiviteBundle:Demystification');
```

You ask Doctrine to load this class :

```
leseulsteve\ActiviteBundle\Entity\Demystification
```

Doctrine also understand the full class name:

```
$this->entityManager->getRepository('leseulsteve\ActiviteBundle\Entity\Demystification');
```

This is a simple convention.

---

Your class seems to be :

```
leseulsteve\GestigrisBundle\Entity\Demystification
```

So you have to ask Doctrine this :

```
$this->entityManager->getRepository('leseulsteveGestigrisBundle:Demystification');
```

Or this :

```
$this->entityManager->getRepository('leseulsteve\GestigrisBundle\Entity\Demystification');
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup Emmanuel pour la réponse, je me doutais bien que ce n'était pas grand chose!

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot (even though this is an old question/response) :)